# mongodb-erlang/bson-erlang how to insert ISODate into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, erlang, bson

I'd like to insert an UTC Date (ISO 8601 Format) field using the ISODate Type into MongoDB.

According to [MongoDB Date Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates) ISODates are stored as UTC Date/Tiem of the [BSONSpec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification). This is \x09 according to this spec. 
[bson-erlang](https://github.com/mongodb/bson-erlang) seems to implement this somehow.

Will research this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the field in erlang's timestamp format ({MegaSecs, Secs, MicroSecs}) and bson-erlang should take care of it.

So e.g.:
Doc = {timestamp, {0, 1000, 100}}